# Formatting Gridview float values by row

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a gridview 'leading_GridView' that's databound to a SQLDataSource.  Many of the values are floats that I would like to format to percentages or decimals rounded to 2 decimal places.  I cannot do this with a DataFormatString because the columns contain different units.  I want to check the values in the first column and format the floats in that row accordingly.

My code:

Columns 1 and 2 contain string data, they're essentially row headers. The following columns contain the float values.

```
<asp:GridView ID="leading_GridView" runat="server" DataSourceID="leading_SqlDataSource" Style="align-content: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" class="centerText gridview" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#33CCCC" BackColor ="Black" BorderColor="#33CCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="3" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records found" Visible="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Indicator" HeaderText="Indicator" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Alias" HeaderText="Alias" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Prev_Year" HeaderText="Prev. Year" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Curr_Year" HeaderText="Curr. Year" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>            
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Query:

```
leading_SqlDataSource.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
leading_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "Select Indicator, Alias, Prev_Year, Curr_Year FROM dbo.line_level";
leading_SqlDataSource.DataBind();
leading_GridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call RowDataboundEvent and after that check specific column value and format as you needed.